# Is there a way to throw IOException in a runnable?

Tags: java

I have some code thats not working(which is a common occurrence for me), but because I am not getting an errors it just continues to run with bad data.  The problem I think is it keeps telling me to wrap parts of my code in try/catch blocks(my tests are basic, I just output a message in the try area and if it gets outputted I assume all went well. All does not seem well in my code). I understand in production, putting a try/catch statement helps the code to continue to run but its making me troubleshooting difficult because I'm trying to troubleshoot that section of my code.

Is there a way around this so I can actually see when something fails within the try area?

Here's a sample of my code:

```
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream baos_back = new ByteArrayInputStream(message);
        ObjectInputStream oos_back = new ObjectInputStream(baos_back);
        i = oos_back.readInt();
        d = oos_back.readDouble();
        list_of_ints = (int[]) oos_back.readObject();
        oos_back.reset();
        baos_back.reset();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you can `throw` the exception to the calling function by adding a `throws` declaration to the method.

Comment: I'd suggest running your code through a debugger and breaking on exceptions.

Comment: Its not part of a method. its within my run() method(basically its opening a channel to a server, pulling data, and converting it).

Comment: Also, in the catch block, you can at least print the stacktrace (along with the value of any method parameters that may be of interest). That would help in debugging.

Comment: @twain249 That doesn't work because he must obey the `Runnable` interface, and `run()` doesn't throw anything.

Comment: @birryree I haven't used a debugger before so I am probably totally off but can it give me errors?  I have seen debuggers used to tell what data is in what variables but I' sure without a try statement my code is throwing a error.

Comment: @learningJava - Debuggers can be used to do a bunch of stuff - you can get the stack trace, set breakpoints that halt program execution at some line of code, check the values of variables, halt every time an exception is thrown...

Comment: I updated code to show you..You gave me the idea of maybe trying to find a blanket catch statement that gives me a stack trace..

Comment: @learningJava - if you just want to see if an exception is getting thrown at all, you can also do a blanket `try { /* stuff */ } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }`, which will catch all `Exception`s, including runtime and checked exceptions. The only things it won't catch are non-Exception Throwables, which are Errors.

Comment: @birryree Thank you so much, that worked and was what I was looking for.  Can you copy/paste it as a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can catch all exceptions in Java with a blanket catch statement:

```
try {
    // code
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will catch every `Exception` thrown in the `try` block, and the only things it won't catch are `Error`s.

In practice, you will want to limit the types of exceptions you catch, and catch more specific exceptions, so you can exception chain as follows:

```
try {
    // code
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // we expected this
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (SomeOtherException soe) { // just an example...
    soe.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Did we expect this? Maybe not!
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above also makes it known that you expect some types of exceptions to occur, and then a big blanket catch-all statement that might catch things you didn't expect.

You can also log exceptions to a file or something else, rather than output them to standard out as this code does right now. A basic logging utility is [`java.util.logging`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html).

---

I still recommend learning to use a debugger though. Debuggers can do a lot of things like halt program execution whenever an exception is thrown, and allow you to inspect the values of variables and fields at any point in the program's execution. If you use Eclipse or Netbeans or IntelliJ or other IDEs, they have debuggers. If you use the command line, there is the `jdb` command-line java debugger.

Comment: thanks so much. I will def. learn debuggers(I only use them for breakpoints right now so I can start my profiler to get a memory dump but I'll focus on their features in eclipse).  Thanks for the great answer and programming advice.

Comment: actually, you triggered a question in my mind...are the integrated debuggers okay or are there 3rd party ones that are better(I'm totally new so not really sure how to define 'better')?

Comment: @learningJava - The debuggers that come with IntelliJ/Eclipse are all pretty good, I have never needed to use an external debugger like JSwat in my years of writing code for Java. Here's a tutorial on [Debugging with Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/). One third party thing I have used was the [Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), to check a Java heap dump to see what caused a machine with 8 GB RAM to crash with `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Thanks Birryree, I'll read up on the link.  I installed Memory Analyzer for eclipse but found it a bit hard to understand(since I was new to java and eclipse), so I got a program called yourkit, that I can pull heap dumps to check what's in memory(if the program crashes then a heap dump is taken automatically).

Comment: @learningJava Yourkit is very nice too - Eclipse MAT takes some getting used to, it was just the first thing I found which wasn't `jhat`, so I used it. I rarely have to use it, but it's nice to know about.

Comment: Your def. right, it can't hurt to expand my toolkit.  I read the link you posted(thanks), I'm going to go through more and get more familiar with the debugging tools.  Thanks so much Birryree.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to get your program to blow up when this error occurs?  If so, you should be able to wrap your `IOException` in a [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and throw that instead.  They're unchecked, so you don't need to declare them and it should kill your program just fine.

Comment: yes, I do want it to blow up when an error occurs.  I'l check out your link, looks promising..

Answer (score 2):

If you want your code to throw the appropriate exception, I'd suggest not using try-catch blocks at all. Try-catch is used to handle exceptions as they arise and then keep running the program, but it sounds like you don't want to handle them at all.

If you do want to use try-catch blocks you could always manually throw a RuntimeException at the end of the catch block.
Something like:

```
throw new IOException();
try {
    // Some code...
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Error handling code...
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest editing your code generation template to do this

```
catch ( $ExceptionClass e )
{
  // TODO: Autogenerated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw new RuntimeExcepton( e );
}
```

This way you have a TODO reminder, a barf on stdout, and are ensured that your program will blow up if you do not provide correct exception handler.